# Mention Types and Mention Classes in Watson Knowledge Studio

Tags: nlp, watson, watson-knowledge-studio

How important are Mention Types and Mention Classes to training a machine learning annotator model? Will they get assigned automatically when entities are highlighted? For example, when you click on the Mention Type tab, “NONE” seems to be preselected. Likewise for “SPC” on the Mention Class tab. None of the videos in IBM's Watson Knowledge Studio playlist covers this aspect of using WKS and the official documentation's explanations of whether and how to properly annotate mentions with these attributes is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you annotate mention types and classes and then train a model, the model can predict them like entities and relations.
However, currently there is no service which can get out put with custom models created by WKS.
So if you want to consume only entities and relations by using the model with services like Natural Language Understanding, Discovery or Watson Explorer, it will be inefficient to assign mention classes and types generally.
It depends on your use case.

All the contents that WKS can provide about training are in the documentation.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/knowledge-studio/index.html